# Log aborted downloads

Tags: nginx, logging

How can I configure nginx to log aborted downloads, i.e. the connection timing out because of client inactivity and/or the client sending an `RST`, while an HTTP response was being sent?

Even sending sending the `error_log` level to `debug`, I don't see anything if a client terminates prematurely.

I want to monitor how many connections are aborted during a download, to detect network interruptions and client problems.

Comment: Nginx already log client abort as `499` status code in access log.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thanks for the comment! But as I understand it, 499 is logged only if the client explicitly closes connection, isn't it? Out of a random sample of 1 million requests my production service got (where I know at least 10000 timed out), just 3 are status 499.